# Where conditions on ActiveRecord associations conflicting with each other in has_many through?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, associations

In my app (Rails 4.2.0.rc2), users can be either students or admins of a given institution. There's an association `:admin_institutions` on `User` that returns all the institutions the user is an admin of by checking their `role` in the join table. There's also an association `:students` on `Institution` that returns all the users who are students at that institution, again according to `institution_users.role`.

These associations work as expected, so I added an association `:admin_students` to `User`, meant to return all the students at all the institutions for which a given user is an admin.

```
class InstitutionUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :institution
  belongs_to :user
end

class Institution < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :institution_users
  has_many :users, :through => :institution_users
  has_many :students, -> { where "institution_users.role = 'Student'" }, :through => :institution_users, source: :user
  ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :institution_users
  has_many :admin_institutions, -> { where "institution_users.role = 'Admin'" }, through: :institution_users, source: :institution
  has_many :admin_students, through: :admin_institutions, source: :students
  ...
end
```

However, `:admin_students` does not work as expected. It generates the following SQL:

> SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "institution_users" ON "users"."id" = "institution_users"."user_id" INNER JOIN "institutions" ON "institution_users"."institution_id" = "institutions"."id" INNER JOIN "institution_users" "institution_users_admin_students_join" ON "institutions"."id" = "institution_users_admin_students_join"."institution_id" WHERE "institution_users_admin_students_join"."user_id" = $1 AND (institution_users.role='Student') AND (institution_users.role = 'Admin')  [["user_id", 190]]

Instead of looking for all the institutions where the user is an admin and selecting all their students, it seems to be looking for institutions where the user is BOTH a student and an admin, so it returns an empty collection.

Is there a way to write an association (as opposed to just a method) that will give me the results I want, without my conditions conflicting like this?

(Side note: Is this the expected behavior for this kind of association? If so, I'd really appreciate further insight into why ActiveRecord interprets it the way it does.)

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer, but maybe it will lead to one.

I'm not a fan of the associations with hard-coded SQL:

```
-> { where "institution_users.role = 'Student'" }
```

They are definitely at least part of the problem because they cannot be interpreted by ActiveRecord to determine which table alias for institution_users to apply it to.

You can allow ActiveRecord that flexibility by referencing a class method of the InsitutionUser model:

```
def self.students
  where(role: "Student")
end
```

This also keeps the InstitutionUser logic all in one place.

Then the association becomes:

```
has_many :students, -> {merge(InstitutionUser.students)}, :through => :institution_users, source: :user
```

Perhaps try it with this and see if that sorts it out for you, and if not it might get things going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! I tried changing it to syntax like `where institution_users: {role: 'Student'}` but got the same result. Then tried your suggestion, but it generates the same query, this time with the roles passed in as arguments. I'll keep poking at it...